# Launch app in foreground doesn't work from cron, but does from terminal

Tags: macos, cron

I have the following:

```
* * * * * open -a /Applications/TextWrangler.app/  ~/notes.txt; open /Applications/Notes.app
```

Neither of the 2 apps brings focus to the foreground (though they do get launched in the background) so the whole job is a bit pointless (it's to remind me to make some notes at the end of each day at work).

It works if I copy and paste the commands into a terminal. So why does cron behave differently and can this be changed?

Comment: Try `reattach-to-user-namespace` (available on homebrew and elsewhere)

Comment: cron jobs can run as your user, but aren't actually part of your user session. Could you use a Launch Agent instead?

Comment: On **macOS High Sierra**, `* * * * * open -a TextWrangler ~/notes.txt; open -a Notes;` works as is for me, both apps come to the front. Try adding `; osascript -e 'tell app "TextWrangler" to activate' -e 'tell app "Notes" to activate'` to the end of your existing _command_ and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: The Applescript approach works so I'm going to go with that. Thanks for the other suggestions. But anything that involves learning a non-transferable skill or install extra software will always be a 2nd choice :) Feel free to post as an answer so I can give credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me on **macOS High Sierra**, e.g.:

```
 * * * * * open -a TextWrangler ~/notes.txt; open -a Notes
```

works as is, both apps come to the front.

Try adding, e.g.:

```
; osascript -e 'tell app "TextWrangler" to activate' -e 'tell app "Notes" to activate'
```

to the end of your existing *command* and see if that makes any difference, e.g.:

```
* * * * * open -a TextWrangler ~/notes.txt; open -a Notes; osascript -e 'tell app "TextWrangler" to activate' -e 'tell app "Notes" to activate'
```

Comment: Personally, I'd put these commands in a shell script file and call the shell script from cron. That would make it much easier to edit and format, without having to worry about cron formatting or anything like that.

Comment: @TJ Luoma, I don't disagree, however it does work as is and as the saying goes, _if it's not broke don't fix it_, but that's up to Sridhar Sarnobat to decide how he wants to handle it. (He asked me to post my comment to his OP as an answer, so I did.)

Comment: I've learnt the hard way that shell scripts to simplify cron entries is counterproductive. You end up unable having difficulty locating the culprit of strange behavior that is caused by a command buried in a shell script whose name is misleading ;)

Comment: @Sridhar Sarnobat, I do not know if you know this, however, `cron` will write an error message to `mail`, which you can access from **Terminal** using the `mail` _command_. That said, the error messages can be cryptic too. :)